# How to add apache-tomcat 7 in Eclipse 4.4 (Luna)

Tags: java, eclipse-luna

I have just installed Eclipse 4.4 (Luna) on Ubuntu, but I couldn't set the Apache Tomcat 7 server in Target Runtime environment. This option is not shown there.

I also tried to add it by menu *Window* → *Preferences → Server → Run time environment. But it also does not work. In it, Download additional server adapter does also not show Apache tomcat server. While apache-tomcat Server properly starts on my System at port 8080.

Comment: Isn't the answer given by @sudhakar right? Do you mind ticking it as correct?

Comment: @SabaAhang It looks like the sudhakar's answer is a copy and paste (with very minimal changes) of Gio's (which was posted a month earlier).

Answer (score 43):

1. go to *Help/Install new Software*
2. choose "*All Available sites*"
3. and search for "*server*"
4. You will see "**Web, Xml, Java EE and OSGi Enterprise Development**"
   Install this Software.

After a restart of Eclipse go to

*Window/Preferences/Server/Runtime Enviroments* 
and click "*add*"

Now you will see the options for Tomcat (in my case Version 3.2 up to 8.0)

Answer (score 23):

1. Go to *Help/Install new Software*
2. Choose "Luna - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/luna"
3. Check "*JST Server Adapters*" and "*JST Server Adapters Extensions*"
4. Once installed, go to "*Window > Preferences > Server > Runtime Environments*"
   and you'll find Apache Tomcat servers

Answer (score 9):

Have you installed the `**Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developer Luna?**` Have you installed or unzip the Tomcat 7 to your local folder? If all answer is yes, you need to add it in Server Environment to your Eclipse:

> ```
> Step1:
>     Click Window menu - Preferences - Server - Runtime Environments 
> Step 2:
>     Click Add - expand Apache - Select Apache Tomcat 7
> Step 3:
>     Browse the Tomcat Installation folder or you can just click   
>     the Download and Install
> Step 4:
>     Click Finished
> ```

Next is add the Server to Server View

> ```
> Step 1:
>     Click Window menu - View - Servers
> Step 2:
>     If you see "No servers available" Click the link to create a new instance
> Step 3:
>     Select "Tomcat v7.0 Server" from Server Type
> Step 4:
>     Select "Apache Tomcat v7.0" from the drop down "Server runtime environment"
> ```

Comment: I tried it but after following first step i.e window-Preferences-Server-Runtime Environments and tried to add tomcat ..there is no option available for Tomcat..it shows other server names except tomcat..

Comment: follow those steps:
Help->Install new software-> http://download.eclipse.org/releases/luna
In the search box type server then install: JST Server Adapters, JST Server Adapters Extensions, JST Server UI, WST Server Adapters
That's All. Hope that helps Salam :)

Answer (score 9):

- Open **Eclipse Luna**
- Choose eclipse `Help > Eclipse Marketplace`

[image]

- Install Eclipse JST Server Adapters

> JST Server Adapter
>
> JST Server Adapter Extensions

- Choose `Window > Preferences > Server > Runtime Environment`

[image]

- Click on `Add` button and select `Apache Tomcat v7.0`

[image]

- Choose the Tomcat server directory and click `Finish`

Answer (score 0):

Create a runtime environment for Tomcat 7, but when you asked for tomcat_home or catalina_home use the path you want. I should run fine. I've made myself on MyEclipse and Tomcat 8. This is very fun because Tomcat 8 is unknown to the MyEclipse is too old. Your Luna is too young and should have a server runtime environment for Tomcat 8. Sure you can use a pro version of eclipse to make it working.

Answer (score 0):

One of the Compatible Tomcat version for eclipse Luna is Eclipse Tomcat Plugin 9.0.1. You can download it from [sourceforge.net](https://sourceforge.net/projects/tomcatplugin/files/updatesite/plugins/)

Download and extract the zipped folder into `..\eclipse\dropins\ folder` and restart the eclipse.