# how to add tomcat in eclipse luna

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I tried answers in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25250835/how-to-add-apache-tomcat-7-in-eclipse-luna), but it doesn't work. 
I checked that I do have JST Server Adapters and the extensions installed, but when I go to Window/Preferences/Server/Runtime Enviroments and click "add", the selections are still not there. Could there be a conflict or I should somehow configure Eclipse? Or is it possible to add manually, what folder should I look for? I installed tomcat8 and also downloaded the .zip, but neither folder is correct.

Eclipse Version: Luna Service Release 1 (4.4.1), and I'm using windows 7.

It seems that now nothing is correct about Eclipse, I installed plugin like AWS toolkit, but it's also nowhere to be found. Now often install new plugin or even update will likely to fail because either of lack of a dependency or can no be found in repository. 
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

There is a link on that preferences page called "Download additional server adapters". Have you tried that, too?

Comment: yes, it gives out error like this: "Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Geronimo Core Feature 2.1.1 (org.apache.geronimo.feature.feature.group 2.1.1)
  Missing requirement: Geronimo Core Feature 2.1.1 (org.apache.geronimo.feature.feature.group 2.1.1) requires 'org.eclipse.jst.feature.group [2.0.0,3.0.0)' but it could not be found"