# Install Tomcat Server on Eclipse Luna running on Ubuntu

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, ubuntu-14.04

I faced issues while installing Tomcat server v8 on eclipse, I followed following [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25250835/how-to-add-apache-tomcat-7-in-eclipse-luna)

But when I go to help-> install software, and select any site in work with, I get as `There are no categorized items`.

What should I do to install tomcat server.

[image]

Comment: This question belong to [ask ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/) or maybe Superuser (I flagged for migration to the latter because migration to ask ubuntu doesn't seem to be possible).

Comment: ok, I will post this on ask ubuntu, Thankx .

Comment: @jPlatte i have posted the question on ask ubuntu but I have not any answer or response. I am unable to post the image as don't have 10 reputation. Can you suggest what should I do?

Comment: Your comment doesn't have a link to your askubuntu question, so I just searched for "tomcat" there. I didn't find a question by you, but did you have a look at the other questions about it there? There are some [existing questions about tomcat](http://askubuntu.com/search?q=tomcat) there.